# problems with coefplot2( ) in R

Tags: r, plot

I've run several MCMCglmm models in R and am looking to plot the regression estimates along with confidence intervals. I'm only interested in plotting the fixed effects, since my random effects are individual actors, individual recipients, and dyads -- and all are statistically unimportant.

Based on Hadfield's tutorials and vignettes, along with a paper by Bolker et al 2012 (Owls examples), I've settled on using `coefplot2()` though `dotchart()` also seems to be an option. I'm using this along with `coeftab()` as follows in the code example below. My issue is that it seems like I *should* be able to skip a bit of the code by using `var.idx` to specify that I only want certain effects plotted; but this is throwing the error `"var.idx: is not a graphical parameter`. I'd like to know if this is about my code, or about the packages I'm using.

My MCMCglmm model is called `m1.teaching`. Here's the code that *is* working for me. I first tabulate the regression estimates/coefficients into a new object:

```
 m1.coefs <- coeftab(m1.teaching)
```

I then create another new object, containing only the mixed effects (present, and r) estimates and confidence intervals:

```
 m1.coefs.present.r <- c(m1.coefs[3:4,])
```

Finally, I plot the estimates and confidence intervals:

```
 coefplot2(m1.coefs.present.r$Estimate, sds=m1.coefs.present.r$'2.5%', varnames=c('present','r'), CI=1)
```

From what I can tell based on the refs above, and the documentation, I should be able to do this without the middle step of creating a new object with just the fixed effects. I want to do this because ultimately I will be showing the effects of several models on a single plot, and long and messy code can lead to mistakes.

The code I think should work, but doesn't:

```
 coefplot2(m1.coefs$Estimate, sds=m1.coefs$'2.5%', var.idx = m1.coefs[3:4,], varnames=c('present','r'), CI=1)
```

This code throws the errors:

```
 Warning messages:
 1: "var.idx" is not a graphical parameter 
 2: "var.idx" is not a graphical parameter 
 3: "var.idx" is not a graphical parameter 
 4: "var.idx" is not a graphical parameter 
 5: "var.idx" is not a graphical parameter 
 6: "var.idx" is not a graphical parameter 
 7: In plot.window(...) : "var.idx" is not a graphical parameter
 8: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : "var.idx" is not a graphical parameter
 9: In title(...) : "var.idx" is not a graphical parameter
```

I'm all out of ideas and resources for understanding this, your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't have `coefplot2` installed, but according to the error message, `var.idx` is not a recognized option.

Comment: Right, but this is strange - because it is listed in the documentation AND used in published papers. Bolker et al use this code: `coefplot2(mfit1,var.idx=c(1,3),ptype="vcov", main="")` and the documentation defines `var.idx` as "the index of the variables: default is to plot all the variables"

Comment: I'm now trying to add a legend, and getting the same error: `"legend" is not a graphical parameter`.

Answer (score 0):

The fixed effects of MCMCglmm models are accessed by `$Sol`. Using `[,]` you can specify which fixed effects you want, the comma specifies all rows which is all of the iterations.

```
coefplot2(m1$Sol[,1:5])
```

Will plot the first 5 fixed effects of the MCMCglmm model `m1`. Note that you can access the level specific random effects with from `$Sol` too.

The random effects are accessed by `$VCV`.

```
coefplot2(m1$VCV[,c(1,3)]
```

will plot the 1st and 3rd random effects of the MCMCglmm model `m1`.